# Does CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element.remove() also remove children?

Tags: ckeditor

Does CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element.remove() remove the element and its descendants or does it just remove the element and stuff its immediate children into its place? I ask because I've tried a number of approaches to removing elements from consideration during a filter and have wound up with not quite the results I expect; removing the element seems not to remove everything it ought to, but perhaps it's intended behavior.

If the latter, what is the most efficient way to remove an element and everything inside it? setHtml()?

Comment: For what it's worth, I have tested, and using `CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element.setHtml("")` does in fact remove the element and its contents.

Answer (score 0):

The [CKEDITOR.htmlParser.node.remove](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlParser.node-method-remove) removes the node which means also its children are removed.

```
// Removing `em` element on `setData`.
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on( 'toHtml', function( evt ) {
    var ems = evt.data.dataValue.find( 'em', true );
    console.log( 'Before: ' + evt.data.dataValue.getHtml() );
    if ( ems.length ) {
        ems[ 0 ].remove();
    }
    console.log( 'After: ' + evt.data.dataValue.getHtml() );
}, null, null, 14 );
```

*See this [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/f1ames/pen/KvzwRN?editors=1010).*

---

It is hard to speculate on your case without seeing any code, but I assume you are trying to manipulate some copy of the element or partial tree which is not used any further so it may seem this method does not work as expected.

If you provide the code, it will be easier to check if there are any issues with it.

Comment: Interesting. When I tried using CKEDITOR.htmlParser.node.remove(), it removed the node but promoted all its child nodes to replace it in the tree, leaving them intact as children of the original node's parent. At least that's what the resulting document looked like...

Comment: Can you try to create a codepen (or similar) demo showing your case? Or just add a code here on SO which reproduces it?